# Minecraft: Can't use mod blocks in my multiplayer server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods, minecraft-java-edition-server

So, basically I have created a multiplayer forge server (1.7.10) and we're trying to place blocks we've created using the Mr Crayfish Furniture Mod (for 1.7.10).

I can see the object on the crafting table once I have put the correct blocks in, but it won't let me pick the item up off the crafting table.

Any suggestions for what might be going wrong?

We originally had a couple of other mods on the server too but every time we attempted to use something, the game would crash for both of us. Super annoying so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to double check if server has SAME versions of mods and if both client and server has SAME mods AND configs.

If client misses some blocks the server has, it won't let you in, however if your client has more mods than server, everything is fine, the client will show you items in crafting etc, however if you really want to get it - server does not know what you do and kicks you out, preventing corruption of data or crash.

So when you say you made some new things by that mod, check that those things got added by server, too.

If everything seems to be good, but crashes are still there - then you have to check the client&server logs&crashlogs. As I know, **this page should not be technical help**, however be free to contact me with them if you need.

Comment: Both the server and my minecraft client have the same mods and same configs. Its not crashing. It just won't let me pick up the item from the crafting table.

Comment: That sounds very much like the server does not know about that crafting recipe, so are you 100% certain the server has the same mods? Can you get any item from said mod though creative on the server? (just op one of you, change to creative and check)